# Timer Control vb.net

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have written a function in a class which runs a report and outputs to excel.
I basically want to time it that how long it has took to generate the report.

Any help?

Comment: actually you want to count the time required to generate the report, isn't it?

Comment: Yes..Iam trying to use stop watch code and have the result as HR/MIN/SEC in a messagebox

Answer (score 1):

this code will help you to find the time required for your operation.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Threading


Class Program

    Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
        Dim stopWatch As New Stopwatch()
        stopWatch.Start()
        Thread.Sleep(10000)
        stopWatch.Stop()
        ' Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value. 
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = stopWatch.Elapsed

        ' Format and display the TimeSpan value. 
        Dim elapsedTime As String = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10)
        Console.WriteLine( "RunTime " + elapsedTime)

    End Sub 'Main
End Class 'Program
```

if it is not enough,Click for Reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx

Comment: With all due respect, your answer has a lot of code to a solution that can be 3 lines of code long...

Comment: for improvements  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Easy Peezy.

You Don;t need a timer.

```
Dim time1 as Date
Dim time2 as Date

'I start generating the report stuff here....
time1 = now
'blablalb
'blab lbah
'report.load (phseudo)

'I am now done with my report code.
time2 = now

msgbox("The time is took was: " & time2.subtract(time1).totalminutes & ":" & time2.subtract(time1).totalseconds)
```